# Unable to use Variable in sql query with values stored in it from other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

I am trying to use the below query. I want to use the `@Names` variable inside the `pivot` query, but I end up with an error. I'm not sure what and where it is wrong.

```
declare @comptype as table(a varchar(1000));
insert into @comptype
Select distinct [pay-component] from tbl_Comp

DECLARE @Names VARCHAR(8000) 

SELECT @Names = COALESCE(@Names + ', ', '') + a
FROM @comptype

SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT [user-id],[currency-code],[paycompvalue], [pay-component] FROM tbl_Comp where [end-date1]='31/12/9999' and [end-date]='31/12/9999')
 as s
PIVOT
(
    SUM(s.[paycompvalue])
    FOR s.[pay-component] IN (@Names)
)AS pivot1
```

Update: 1

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 37
Incorrect syntax near '@Names'.
```

Let me know if further details required.

Comment: Could you add the error description please ?

Comment: Updated the error description.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because you can't use a variable in the pivot operator? Try to put the whole query in a variable, something like that:

```
declare @query varchar(max)

set @query = '
    SELECT  *
    FROM    (
            SELECT  [user-id]
                    ,[currency-code]
                    ,[paycompvalue]
                    ,[pay-component]
            FROM    tbl_Comp
            where   [end-date1]=''31/12/9999'' and [end-date]=''31/12/9999''
            ) as s
    PIVOT   (
            SUM(s.[paycompvalue])
            FOR s.[pay-component] IN (' + @Names + ')
            ) AS pivot1
'

execute sp_executesql @query
```

Answer (score 0):

Either try 
insert into @comptype(a)

or check if the query 
Select distinct [pay-component] from tbl_Comp 
is correct

The error is not in line mentioned by the error message, but the previous statement